# What's wrong with the pointers

Tags: c

I am learning pointers in C language. I have written a simple code of pointers using. I have no errors, but the program `iz` freezing in the middle of execution. What could be the reason for that?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

void main()   
{
    int i;
    int *i2;
    i2 = &i;

    int z;
    int *z2;
    z2 = &z;   

    int b = 0;
    int *b2;
    b2 = &b;  

    char ch[250];
    //char *ch2;
    //ch2 = &ch;   

    printf("%s\n", " Enter line not longer than 250 characters");
    gets_s(ch); 

    for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; i2++)
    {
        if (*i2>4)
        {
            *z2 = *i2;
            *b2++;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d%c", *b2, ch[*z2]);
}
```

Comment: Do NOT edit your question so as to invalidate answers!

Answer (score 5):

A big problem is your `for` loop:

```
for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; i2++)
```

`i2++` increments the value of the *pointer* (making it point to something other than `i`), not the thing being *pointed to*.  You need to change that line to

```
for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; (*i2)++)
```

The parentheses around `*i2` are necessary, because the postfix `++` operator has higher precedence than the unary `*` operator.  `*i2++` would be parsed as `*(i2++)`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; i2++)
```

should be

```
for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; (*i2)++)
```

---

**NOTE:** 
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked a second question when you edited your original question (that edit has now been reversed so the actual question has disappeared).

Basically you asked why the printf statement was not returning the expected value.
At that time you had this code:

```
for (*i2 = 0; *i2<10; (*i2)++)
{
    if (*i2>4)
    {
        *z2 = *i2;
        *b2++;
            break;
    }
}
printf("%d%c\n", b2, ch[z]);
```

b2 is a pointer ... int *b2;
Now you assign a value to b2 ... b2 = &b;
So now b2 contains the address b and your printf statement prints this address (albeit in integer format '%d' rather than as a pointer %p)

To get the value held in 'b' which is 'pointed to by 'b2', you need to dereference ... *b2

But ... note that you have changed the pointer *b2 with this statement  ... *b2++
That statement changed the value of the pointer, not the value of b which it originally pointed to and now *b2 will be undefined.

Change *b2++ to (*b2)++ and change printf b2 to printf *b2
and the result is b + 1 which will be 1 as b was originally set to 0.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanx a lot. Was asking this question in several places, but couldn't get any solution